# update .htaccess to URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a URL that looks like:

url.com/show.php?id=abc 
url.com/show.php?id=xxx 
How would I go about converting that URL to
url.com/abc
url.com/xxx

How do I go about making friendly URLs in PHP?

Comment: See also: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like the following in your .htaccess file

```
#Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ show.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```